# WPF Base Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to use a BaseWindow for other windows in WPF, but I'm getting errors that I don't know how to fix.

I created a base class:

```
namespace Evolutio.FluXus.WPFApp
{
    public partial class WindowBase : Window
    {
    }
}
```

And changed my LoginView.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class LoginView : WindowBase, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IUserAppService _userAppService;

    public LoginView(IUserAppService userAppService)
    {
        _userAppService = userAppService;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And I'm getting an error in the `Close()` statement.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to inherit WindowBase in the other part of of your parial LoginView class (the Xaml code):

```
<local:WindowBase x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Evolutio.FluXus.WPFApp"
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander! A really dumb mistake! :-)